# How to import time data in the format of “M-d-y h-m”?

Tags: python, dolphindb

The sample data from csv is shown as follows:

```py
datetime,symbol,price,volume
10/1/2020 9:00,XYZ,10.68,375
10/1/2020 9:00,XYZ,10.9,66
10/1/2020 9:00,XYZ,11.42,103
10/1/2020 9:00,XYZ,12.62,280
10/1/2020 9:00,XYZ,10.73,23
10/1/2020 9:00,XYZ,11.44,299
10/1/2020 9:00,XYZ,12.66,152
10/1/2020 9:00,XYZ,11.04,401
10/1/2020 9:00,XYZ,10.61,392
10/1/2020 9:00,XYZ,11.21,473
```

I executed the following line to read the data:

```py
schemaTB = extractTextSchema(csvFile)
update schemaTB set type="DATETIME" where name="datetime"
schemaTB[`format]=["M-d-y h:m:s",,,];
t = loadText(csvFile,,schemaTB)
```

But it reported an error:

```py
t = loadText(csvFile, , schemaTB) => Invalid temporal format M-d-y h:m:s
```

Comment: you are probably looking for this type of format: [formats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#:~:text=strptime(date_string%2C%20format)-,strftime()%20and%20strptime()%20Format,a%20standard%20C%20implementation.,-Directive)

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas for this task.
First you should read the date time column with the correct type while importing your csv. Then you convert to the desired format:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csvFile, sep=",", parse_dates=['datetime'])
df["datetime"].dt.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             datetime symbol  price  volume
0 2020-10-01 09:00:00    XYZ  10.68     375
1 2020-10-01 09:00:00    XYZ  10.90      66
2 2020-10-01 09:00:00    XYZ  11.42     103
3 2020-10-01 09:00:00    XYZ  12.62     280
4 2020-10-01 09:00:00    XYZ  10.73      23
5 2020-10-01 09:00:00    XYZ  11.44     299
6 2020-10-01 09:00:00    XYZ  12.66     152
7 2020-10-01 09:00:00    XYZ  11.04     401
8 2020-10-01 09:00:00    XYZ  10.61     392
9 2020-10-01 09:00:00    XYZ  11.21     473
```

Edit: you can even directly import in the right format with a lambda function:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csvFile, sep=",", parse_dates=['datetime'], date_parser=lambda d: pd.Timestamp(d).strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```